# Implementation of Automatic Update server and Client using PUSH Method

Tags: .net, wcf

i have my software(.NET) running on clients. I need to push the updates to the clients over web whenever new update available .

I thought to implement a web service which is running on the main server which broadcasts the update notifications to the client. For dat, CLient has to register their identity over the web to the server.

Server will send the notification on availability of the update. Client have to download the update from the server.(i.e.) Server will start the upload process and client have to download.

I don't want a program always running in client machine and checking for a update.

Will WCF would be the good option? .. Is that possible to implement? .. I know there are so many constraints in the networked environment. Suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For software updates I wouldn't do push notifications unless the client software is always running. A better option might be to have the client check with the server for new updates when the software first starts up. There is less to maintain and it's easier to implement. With push notifications there always has to be a listener on the client side and it's possible for clients to close the listener. You'll also have the overhead of maintaining a manifest of all the connections. If all the clients are running on the same network, click once deployment might be an option. It allows you to configure it so that when new updates are released the client must update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement push feature from server to client. You just need to maintain connected client list in your server by storing instance context object of each client using WCF service and call callback method which will be implemented at client side. So all clients will get update through callback method.

You can store instance context object of client like below, where Client list is hash table:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class HostService : IHostService
    {

    public bool Connect(Guid applicationId)
    {
    if (!ClientList.ContainsKey(applicationId))
                        {
                            IHostServiceCallback client = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IHostServiceCallback>();
    ClientList.Add(applicationId, client);
    }
}
```

Interface for host service :

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IHostServiceCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public partial interface IHostService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Connect(Guid applicationId);
}
```

Callback class for service :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public partial interface IHostServiceCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendNotification(string message);
}
```

When your server receive notification in any event handler, send it to all clients like :

```
private void Notification_Received(object sender, EventReceivedEventArgs e)
{
foreach (IHostServiceCallback client in ClientList.Values)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.SendNotification(notificationMessage);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
}
```

In client application, you have implemented callback method like :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, IHostServiceCallback
{
    public void SendNotification(string message)
    {
           // do some operation
    }
}
```